# multinomial hypothesis testing

Tags: probability, statistics, hypothesis-testing

Suppose we have data $(X_1, X_2, X_3)$ (I'll refer the categories as 1, 2, 3) that has a multinomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $(p_1, p_2, p_3)$ and we want to test the hypothesis that $p_1>p_2>p_3$.  I am trying to figure out an exact testing procedure for this.

One idea I had would be to first condition $X_3$ on $X_1$ i.e. see how many times 3 was realized when the options were 3 and 2 only.  According to the hypothesis, this should be less than 1/2 and we could construct a simple binomial test for this since $X_3|X_1$ has a binomial distribution with parameters $n-X_1$ and $\frac{p_3}{p_2+p_3}$ and reject if the realization of 3 exceeded some critical value $k$.

Secondly, we could perform a similar test for $X_2|X_3$ and if the hypothesis is true we should see 2 chosen less than half the time when the options are only 1 or 2.  A similar binomial test would work for testing this.  Overall, we could reject the original hypothesis if either of these tests reject.
However, controlling size seems difficult to me in this case since the tests are not independent (at least they obviously seem to not be).

Is there a better approach to testing this hypothesis?  I have considered confidence intervals for the $p$'s, but not sure if I should use two-side or one-sided.  I have seen procedures for confidence intervals for $p_i-p_j$ for $i\neq j$, but these rely on asymptotic approximations.
Anyway, any help or suggestions or references would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a problem that your two tests are somewhat dependent because if you assume that the sum of observations is fixed, then $p_1 \leq p_2$ DECREASES the chance that $p_2 \leq p_3$. So you'll actually be conservative if you only reject when one of the tests rejects. Since you only need one test to reject, you have a multiple hypothesis testing issue so you should divide your $p$-value cutoff for each test by 2.

Comment: Ok so if I want the level of the test to be $\alpha=.05$ then I assign $\alpha/2$ to each of the individual tests I describe above and this would be conservative due to the dependence between the two tests i.e. size will be < .05, correct?  Also, does it matter that I am developing the test based on strict inequalities rather than weak?  Specifically, it seems like I am doing things backwards by trying to control size based off rejection of a hypothesis that does not have a weak inequality which is not the standard way to write a null hypothesis.

Comment: Since your assumption is that the counts are discrete and sum of two counts is fixed in each case, for your strict inequality null hypothesis all you need to do is include the case that the counts could have been equal when appropriate when you are evaluating the one-sided $p$-value. However this should never change your conclusions because if the equality case is included in the cases for which you are computing the $p$-value, then your $p$-value should not be significant. And yes, $\alpha / 2$ is the canonical level for each of your tests if you want an overall level of $\alpha$.

Comment: As a side note, if you have prior beliefs (i.e. before you see the data) about which inequality will be violated, you can assign different levels to your two tests to come up with an overall level of $\alpha$. All you need is that the two levels add up to $\alpha$.

Comment: That was along the lines of my intuition... thanks for your help!